# Is it possible to conditionally format the font colour of one column based on the value of another?

Tags: tableau-api, conditional-formatting

I have a workbook which identifies valid and invalid names for certain elements within my dataset.

I want to change the colour of the font in each column to the left of wherever the word `Invalid` appears to red, and to green wherever `Valid` is shown.

In the example screenshot I provide, I want the value under `Identity Data.Name` to be listed in red whenever the value of `Val Department` reads `Invalid department` and green whenever it reads `Valid department`.  The same goes for the other columns in the example, too.

(Note that I have narrowed some columns to protect sensitive data, but it doesn't affect the relevance of the image.)

[image]

Comment: You can colour by the value of a single field. Since you already have the yes/no defined in your data you could simply drag one of these fields to colour. If you want to colour different columns by different fields you'd have to create individual charts then put them together in a dashboard.

Comment: Two things worth trying. 1. You can color by two discrete fields if you hold the SHIFT key down when you place the second field on the color shelf. (this has the effect of creating a combined field and coloring by that). 2. Tableau introduced the ability to have a different color legend per measure in version 10.2 https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/whatsnew_server.htm#Legends_per_measure

Answer (score 0):

You have to drag the dimension text you want colored into the Label mark. That is the only way to do conditional font color in Tableau, that I know of.